# Can 1 PHP file connects to 2 databases?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to the first database to pull some information, then update a table in the second database with that information.

However, the second query always tries to pull from the first database if I don't close the connection.  If I do close the connection, then it gives me a socket error.

I am using Drupal (so my first database is the Drupal database).  I want to get a value from one of those tables and put it in my Member Info database whenever 1 of 3 different PHP pages load.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can just update the selected database in PHP with the mysql_update_db function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: @MSost Please don't use `mysql_`, instead, use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create multiple connections. You need to specify the link inside mysql_query as second arguements.

Example :

```
$link1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link1) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// second foo1
$db_selected_1 = mysql_select_db('foo1', $link1);
if (!$db_selected_1) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link2) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// select foo2
$db_selected_2 = mysql_select_db('foo2', $link2);
if (!$db_selected_2) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

// query on first db
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE 1', $link1);

// query on second db
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE 1', $link2);
```

If you have the same crendetials on the same server for both database, you could just do this :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// select foo1
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo1', $link);

// query on first db
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE 1', $link);

// select foo2
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo2', $link);

// query on second db
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE 1', $link);
```

I however suggest you to use `mysqli_` or even `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple connections concurrently.

There is no limit in PHP that will stop you from doing that.

If you're having a problem with specific code, please update the question.